# How to redirect page to url by shortcut key

Tags: javascript, shortcut

I have code for shortcut key and when i click on that key it opens the url in a new window, but I want to have my current page be redirected to that url; the url should open in the same page.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which
        if (keyCode == 17&&81) {
            window.open("urltest.html");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your `if (keyCode == 17&&81)` is exactly the same as `if (keyCode == 17)`. Did you mean `if (keyCode == 17 || keyCode == 81)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the url of the current page, simply assign to [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)

```
if (keyCode == 17&&81) {
    window.location = "urltest.html";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The [`window.location`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) object can be used to get the current page address (URL) and to redirect the browser to a new page.

```
if (keyCode == 17&&81) {
    window.location = "SomePage.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `window.open("urltest.html");` with `window.location = "urltest.html";`